# Wallpaper only shows up after booting from USB

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, desktop-background

After I boot my PC with Ubuntu 12.04 from USB drive, it only shows the wallpaper.

I'm able to access the terminal, and the system files through making a folder.

I tried doing the `unity --reset` but that doesn't work. Thanks, I'm also new to Ubuntu.